# Proving Integral with Riemann Zeta Function

Tags: integration, riemann-zeta

I need some help showing that

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^se^xdx}{e^x-1} = s!\zeta(s).$$

I tried doing a $u$ sub where $u=e^x$, and then I tried integrating by parts, but I was left with the integral $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{s(\ln u)^{s-1}du}{u(u-1)}$, and I'm fairly certain this isn't the way to go. I know that $\Gamma(n) = \int_0^{\infty}{x^{n-1}}{e^xdx}$, but I don't know how I can apply this identity to this proof, if at all.

Comment: Something is wrong with this question. Please check for typos, for start you have $\frac{1}{e^s-1}$ in the denominator, later $\frac1{u-1}$ appears. And even if it was $\frac{1}{e^x-1}$ the integral still wouldn't converge. However there is one similar identity that might work:
$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^s}{e^x-1}dx=s!\zeta(s+1)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Employ the geometric series and the evaluation
$$
\frac{{s!}}{{n^{s+1} }} = \int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - nx} x^{s} dx} .
$$
(Can you prove this integral representation?)